# Speed on recurrent graphs

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

Suppose that $G$ is a (locally finite) graph such that the simple random walk on $G$ is recurrent. Does this imply any upper bound on the speed $\mathbb{E}d(X_t,X_0)$ of such random walk?

Comment: can you please define the speed precisely?

Comment: @DelioM. : we start a random walk at point X_0 and look at the expected distance from X_0 after t steps (this might a priori depend on the choice of X_0).

Comment: i see. i don't know exactly what kind of estimates you are looking for, but you might find something relevant for you in §1.5 of fan chung's *spectral graph theory* or in chapter 1 of woess' *random walks on infinite graphs and groups*.